# program appears to continue running after exit (0)

Tags: c++

At runtime, the program takes one or more arguments from the command line, each of which is the name of files to open.

argc == the number of filenames.

argv[0] == the program's name.

argv[n] , where n is an integer == a given filename, according to the order in which they are passed from the command line.

next_file advances to the next file to be edited. it increments n, and exits if n is greater than argc; since that would mean the last file had already been reached. otherwise, it calls file_handler.

file_handler takes a stream object [file], a string [name], and a boolean variable [open]. if open is 0, it closes the current file. if open is 1, it opens [name] with [file].

when next_file is called, the expected behavior is that it will close the currently open file, advance [n] by one, and then open the next file. it should exit before attempting to open a file that doesn't exist.

the function works normally until the last file is reached, at which point a debug assertion is thrown.

```
void next_file ( int & n , int argc , char *argv [] , fstream & file )
{
    n++;
    if ( n > argc )
        exit ( 0 );
    file_handler ( file , argv [n - 1] , 0);
    file_handler ( file , argv [n] , 1 ); //this appears to be the cause of the assertion failure
}

void file_handler ( fstream & file , string name , bool open )
{
    if ( open == 0 )
    {
        file.close ();
        file.clear ();
        return;
    }
    in.open ( name , ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary );
    if ( !in.is_open () )
    {
        cout << "\n Failed opening " << name << "\n\n";
        exit (0);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you sure it executed that if statement that includes the `exit (0)` ? Stepped through a debugger?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include that, I've edited in a comment at the line in question.

Comment: Why not use the `bool` type instead of `int` flags? Or even better, a suitable enumeration.

Comment: I also confirmed that [n] is being updated correctly, and it reaches its stopping value ( i.e. 1 + argc ) before the failure.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf which int flag are you referring to?

Comment: If argc is 1, there is 1 element in argv, argv[0], which is the program make. So argc+1 is wrong

Comment: @kfsone got it. that's strange, in a previous version of the program I was using n > argc with no problems. anyway, n > argc - 1 fixed it. thanks very much.

Comment: @srcs: the `bool open` flag. OK, it's declared as `bool`. But you're comparing it with `int` values, and treating it as an `int`. That may be due to bad naming. E.g. name it `is_open`, then write just `if( not is_open )` instead of `if( open == 0 )`.

Comment: Aside from that, your code looks incredibly non-idiomatic. It looks like the work of someone who knows some other language and is learning how to express code from that language with C++ keywords. Please show your main routine so someone can help you simplify and eliminate the need for these weird hoops you're going thru

Comment: @kfsone What do you mean by non-idiomatic? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @srcs Honestly? It's basically the inside-out diametric opposite of what a C++ programmer would do. You're using RAII containers (fstream) in an RAII antipattern (you've written code to explicitly close and clear an fstream instead of using the RAII pattern it's built for). See http://ideone.com/SytKu7

Comment: @kfsone Should I not be closing files after I'm done using them?

Comment: @srcs If you wrote your code idiomatically, you wouldn't need to. In the code I linked the files are implicitly closed.

Answer (score 1):

You running off the end of the array.

As you know, when an array has `n` elements, they are values `array[0]` through `array[n-1]`.

```
n++;
if ( n > argc )
    exit ( 0 );
```

At this point, the highest possible value for `n` is `argc`, because if `n > argc`, `exit(0)` gets called. But when `n` is equal to `argc`, this will proceed. Therefore:

```
file_handler ( file , argv [n] , 1 ); //this appears to be the cause of the assertion failure
```

Of course this will be the cause of the assertion. The highest value of `n` here will be `argc`, as explained above.

And, of course, `argv[argc]` does not exist. There are `argc` values in `argv`, therefore the last one will be `argv[argc-1]`.

In actuality, the way that `argv` argument to `main()` is set up, `argv[argc]` will return a `nullptr`. This parameter to `file_handler()` is a `std::string`, and the attempt to construct a `std::string` from a `nullptr` is going to raise your assert.

Answer (score 0):

For the `main` arguments, the value of `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to be ​0​.

Then, with `n` == `argc`,

```
file_handler ( file , argv [n] , 1 )
```

… is equivalent to

```
file_handler ( file , 0 , 1 )
```

… where the 0 is used to initialize a `std::string` formal argument, which is rather ungood.